How can I disable pinch zoom webkitgtk?
Everytime I zoom in on the touch pad webkit freezes. This might be due to a bug in the webkit.
#include <webkit/webkit.h>
static void create_window(GtkApplication *app, gpointer data)){
    const gchar *uri = "https://www.example.com";
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    GtkWidget *webview = webkit_web_view_new();
    gtk_window_set_child((GtkWindow *)window, webview);
    gtk_window_maximize((GtkWindow *)window);
    gtk_window_present((GtkWindow *)window);
    webkit_web_view_load_uri((WebKitWebView *)webview, uri);
}

int main(int response, char **name)
{
    GtkApplication *app = gtk_application_new("com.example.webapp", 0);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", (GCallback)create_window, NULL);
    response = g_application_run((GApplication *)app, response, name);
    g_object_unref(app);
    return response;
}

When I pinch and zoom it freezes with the following error
Received invalid message: 'DrawingArea_CommitTransientZoom'

What signal can i use to filter out pinch zooming

You can connect to the WebKitWebView's web-process-terminated signal. You can also use GTK's event signal. WebKitGTK does not provide direct signal for the pinch gestures. If you still find any problem try searching through GTK library.

web-process-terminated caches the event after the crash I woull like to catch it before it crashes so that i can ignore it. Which signal is gtk event signal. any link to a documentation
